# MVC CQRS App - making it so remote workers can work with no fuss

Tags: domain-driven-design, nservicebus, cqrs

I got my ting set up with NSB, and MVC3, RAvenDb and common domain etc  -works like a charm

Now - the MVC layer only pushes commands to the NSB and reads from the readmodel  directly using the DocumentSession provided by RavenDb

My question is - I don't want the UI devs to have to configure and fire a raven console server and the read and write servers with NSB

How do other people handle this?

I want the MVC app to be fire-able without any of that.

What do you do?

Comment: You could also invest in making the experience better for the UI developer and use e.g. an embedded RavenDb instance combined with running all your handlers in process. Think of it as a profile they can use while developing in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a simple wrapper around NSB specifics, similar to what is being suggested.  You don't have to use full IOC, but you can at least use a Factory.  Here is the interface definition(I can follow up with the NSB implementation if you so require):

```
public interface IServiceBusAgent<T>
{
   void Send(Action<T> messageConstructor);
   void Send(String destination, Action<T> messageConstructor);
   void Send(String destination, String correlationId, Action<T> messageConstructor);
   void SendLocal(Action<T> messageConstructor);
}

public class NServiceBusAgent<T> : IServiceBusAgent<T> where T : IMessage
{
    private readonly IBus bus;

    public NServiceBusAgent() : this(null) { }

    public NServiceBusAgent(IBus bus)
    {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void Send(Action<T> messageConstructor)
    {
        if (null != messageConstructor)
            this.bus.Send<T>(messageConstructor);
    }

    public void Send(String destination, Action<T> messageConstructor)
    {
        Send(destination, String.Empty, messageConstructor);
    }

    public void Send(String destination, String correlationId, Action<T> messageConstructor)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");

        if (null != messageConstructor)
            this.bus.Send<T>(destination, correlationId, messageConstructor);
    }

    public void SendLocal(Action<T> messageConstructor)
    {
        if (null != messageConstructor)
            this.bus.SendLocal<T>(messageConstructor);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the NSB bits? I'd be interested in seeing it. tnx

Comment: Inserted the other code, for web apps we get a reference to the Bus from an HttpModule we wrote and we access it right of the module.

Answer (score 0):

We communicate with the "backend" from our webservice via interfaces.
When starting up the web we use the IOCC/DI Pattern to use real or dev mode instances of that interface.

For example your "OrderCommandApplication" that would contain commands to create orders would have an interface IOrderCommandApplication. now depending on the developer who starts the web we inject either the DemoOrderCommandApplication which only persists state in memory or the OrderCommandApplication which uses ravendb/wcf whatever.
Look at for example [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html) or for some basics search for Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern.

Comment: I'm cool with DI. It's just I don't have that extra layer. In my mvc app I either push direct to the bus or pull direct from doc session. I was thinking about faking all that and switching config but wondered how others were doing it.

Comment: When I say extra layer, I mean the services between nsb/raven and mvc.

Comment: with the above mentioned method you can easily create a new demoinstance that just does nothing. this is far more easier to implement then to look at how to change the config according to your requirements.

Comment: what i'm saying is - there is no demoinstance - i am trying to keep unnecessary layers out. i talk directly to the doc session and bus in the mvc. I can see how yours works.